# Mail::Send from address

Tags: perl

Is there a way to define from address with [Mail::Send](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail%3a%3aSend) package.

I tried below

```
my $email = new Mail::Send;
$email->from('eTEC');
```

but it is giving below error.

> Can't locate object method "from" via package "Mail::Send" at
>   unix-mail1.pl line 11.

Regards#Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source code, it doesn't support `from()`, which means it won't support it in the constructor. You need to `set()` it manually which will be picked up and handled by `Mail::Mailer` (part of the MailTools package) when you call `open()`.

```
my $email = Mail::Send->new(to => );
$email->set('From', 'eTEC');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the documentation for [Mail::Send](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail%3a%3aSend) which indicates that it supports a `from` method. So I'm not sure why you think it exists.

In general, modules in the "Mail" namespace are older and less useful than modules in the "Email" namespace. I recommend that you look at [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) (or even [Email::Sender::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender%3a%3aSimple)).

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but try `Mail::Send->new(From => 'your@email')`